# What is the difference between asu and ashita?

Tags: grammar

I've seen asu and ashita both used as furigana for the same kanji (明日).

Is there a big, subtle or no difference in meaning and usage?

Comment: I recall these questions, please also have a look at them:

http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14385/%E6%98%8E%E6%97%A5-%E3%81%82%E3%81%99-%E3%81%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-is-there-a-difference-in-meaning-and-when-each-is-used

http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14731/why-sometimes-people-change-the-way-they-say-%E6%98%8E%E6%97%A5-from-%E3%81%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-to-%E3%81%BF%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A1-or-%E3%81%82%E3%81%99-when-con

Answer (score 1):

My dictionary says あす is more polite than あした.

And 明日 has an another reading like みょうにち and this is more polite あす.

I know みょうにち is polite but I didn't know あす is more polite than あした. I think Japanese who know this difference isn't many.